# Asus Screen freeze issue [ X550LC ]

Tags: nvidia, screen, hardware, bug-reporting

Is there any package to fix this or do I always have to resort to use Ctrl+Alt+F2/F7...

Hardware info here:

- sudo lshw -short > http://pasted.co/11cae3a3
- lscpi -k > http://pasted.co/b6b9f6d3
- Using ubuntu 14.04

Where do I file a bug in launchpad...

Comment: What is the Ubuntu version? Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -k | grep -EA2 'VGA|3D'` terminal command.

Comment: I have a very similar laptop, and had the same problem on Trusty. I've never identified the exact cause, but upgrading from Trusty to Vivid fixed it for me.

Comment: @Pilot6 updated in edits...

Answer (score 0):

You need to install Nvidia drivers. Run in terminal

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-352 nvidia-prime
```

and reboot.

And it is not a bug at all.

Comment: didn't work buddy.. tried.. :(